# Error in MySql syntax on INNER JOIN use

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to check if a username it was already chosen. Before of show the query this is my tables structure:

**USER**

```
ID | data

 5    0
 6    1
```

**USERS_SETTINGS**

```
ID | Username

 5    Dillinger
 6    John
```

How you can see in the table `user` I've a list of all users available in the system and in the `users_settings` table I've the settings of each user of `user` table. Now if a customer who is registering in the system chose the username `Dillinger` an error message appear 'cause the username has already chosen, instead, if the customer chose John the system doesn't show any error 'cause there was already a registered user with the username but was deleted **`data: 1`**.
What I tried:

```
query = "SELECT Count(username) from users_settings u
                                INNER JOIN user id d ON
                                u.id = d.id
                                WHERE u.username = @usernamep AND
                                d.data = @datap"
```

But when I do `.ExecuteScalar` I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use neare 'd ON u.id = d.id 'at line 2

What is wrong exactly?

Comment: So "data" stands for "deleted"? Why don't you name it "deleted"?

Comment: @etalon11 name field is not a problem

Comment: I know, but it is not Clean Code :-)

Comment: @etalon11 I don't agree. It's just a flag no code.

Comment: Clean Code is not only for Code. Clean Code says that naming is essential. It has to be precise and has to be understood by it's Name and not by additional informations like comments or Else. If you would not have mentioned what "data" stands for, no one would have understood what it is for. "data" is one of the worst names for a variable or column Name. Sorry but in this cases we don't share the Same opinion.

Comment: No problem but: "... the username but was deleted data: 1 ..." I've explained well so I don't understand really.

Comment: But what happens if a other Person has to maintain your Code. It would be difficult to unterstand what "data" stands for. So you can make life to your colleagues much easier if your naming is precise and clear to unterstand.

Comment: My code, but my app in general are all documented and the code also is commented. You can call the variable "deleted" but you will never be 100% sure of what deleted is stand for.

Comment: I'll give up to. But I Do not aggree with your opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to assign two different alias (or a typo) to a table which is not valid and should be changed to :

```
query = "SELECT Count(username) 
         FROM users_settings u INNER JOIN user d 
         ON u.id = d.id
         WHERE u.username = @usernamep 
         AND   d.data = @datap"
```

Comment: Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Do you have `id` column in your `user_settings` table?

Comment: Of course, for this the error is strange. Maybe the letter u isn't recognized?

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the problem with the syntax:

```
select count(*)
from user u join
     user_settings us
     on u.id = us.id -- I am guessing about the right column name here
where u.username = @usernamep and us.data = @datap;
```

However, this is more expensive than it might need to be.  A cheaper method uses `exists` rather than `count()`:

```
select 1
from user u
where u.username = @usernamep and
      exists (select 1
              from user_settings us
              where u.id = us.id and us.data = @datap
             )
limit 1;
```

A user already exists if this returns any rows.  For best performance, you want an index on `user(username)` and `user_settings(user_id, data)`.

Comment: I get Unknown column us.id in ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
query = "SELECT Count(username) from users_settings u
                            INNER JOIN user d ON
                            u.id = d.id
                            WHERE u.username = @usernamep AND
                            d.data = @datap"
```